# entering objects in an ArrayList with while loop

Tags: java

I can't get this code to work. While entering objects in an `ArrayList`, the program asks you if you want to continue, but it skips that line and goes on to ask again for the name (nombre).

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Personas> persona = new ArrayList<Personas>();
    char salir = 'S';
    String nombre;
    int edad;
    while (salir == 'S') {
        System.out.print("\n Nombre: ");
        nombre = scan.next();
        System.out.print(" edad: ");
        edad = scan.nextInt();

        persona.add(new Personas(edad, nombre));
        System.out.print(" desea ingresar mas datos (Y/N)");

    }
    for (Personas datos : persona) {
        System.out.println(datos);
    }
}


public class Personas {
 private String nombre;
 private int edad;


   public Personas (int edad, String nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;

    }
   @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return "\n nombre: " + nombre + "\n edad:" + edad ;
    }

    public String getFirst ()
    {
        return nombre;
    }
    public int getLast ()
    {
        return edad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are checking what your entered ?

Comment: Why `salir == 'S'` check is there ?  It should be `Y` or `N` right?

Comment: salir = 'S'  and you are checking  while (salir == 'S') so don't expect it to get out of while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never change your variable `salir` to anything else than `'S'`. So your loop will run endlessly. Add a statement reading a new Value for your `salir` variable into your loop.

```
salir = (char) System.in.read();
```

Your should also change the initial value from `salir` to `'Y'` and accordingly in the while check also. You're expecting an input of `'Y'` or `'N'` so checking for `'S'` will always be false once you give your users the option to enter something.

Comment: Thanks Aron it works now.... also I didnt realize that char is case sensitive..so I change it to lower case...now I am wondering why it needed a  throws IOException when I added your line........  thanks to Ivan Jovovic for editing my post too

Comment: @Lazaro Because it's a stream you're reading directly from, this could lead to such an Exception. You can either add this to the throws part of your main method or just surround it with a try...catch block.

Comment: Great! Thanks again Aron.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan in a user input to change the value of `salir` in the `while` loop. Currently, it's a continuous `while` loop, like while(true).

Answer (score 0):

The loop:

```
while (salir == 'S') {
    System.out.print("\n Nombre: ");
    nombre = scan.next();
    System.out.print(" edad: ");
    edad = scan.nextInt();

    persona.add(new Personas(edad, nombre));
    System.out.print(" desea ingresar mas datos (Y/N)");

}
```

is wrong. You're not changing the value of your variable `salir` so it will keep looping unless you change it. You can do something like this to solve it:

```
while (salir == 'S') {
    System.out.print("\n Nombre: ");
    nombre = scan.next();
    System.out.print(" edad: ");
    edad = scan.nextInt();

    persona.add(new Personas(edad, nombre));
    System.out.print(" desea ingresar mas datos (S/N)");
    salir = scan.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a line in your code and it should work, the system needs to read the `char` entered by the user either:

```
salir = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

So the full code is;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Personas> persona = new ArrayList<Personas>();
    char salir = 'Y';
    String nombre;
    int edad;
    while (salir == 'Y') {
        System.out.print("\n Nombre: ");
        nombre = scan.next();
        System.out.print(" edad: ");
        edad = scan.nextInt();

        persona.add(new Personas(edad, nombre));
        System.out.print(" desea ingresar mas datos (Y/N)");
        salir = scan.next().charAt(0);

    }
    for (Personas datos : persona) {
        System.out.println(datos);
    }
}


public static class Personas {
 private String nombre;
 private int edad;


   public Personas (int edad, String nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;

    }
   @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return "\n nombre: " + nombre + "\n edad:" + edad ;
    }

    public String getFirst ()
    {
        return nombre;
    }
    public int getLast ()
    {
        return edad;
    }
}
```

I just tested it and it works.

You can use:

```
System.in.read();
```

But note that it'll throw `IOException`because `System.in` is an `InputStream` which throws an `IOException` ... so you must catch it before it throws `IOException`.

Comment: Thanks M-Y it works too, now I am wondering why your line doesnt ask me to add:  (throws IOException), and the line that Aron gave me:    (salir = (char) System.in.read();) does.

Comment: Glad it worked.. Well, `System.in` is an `InputStream` which throws an `IOException` ... so you must catch it before it throws `IOException`.

Comment: The reason I didn't use scan.next().charAt(0) is, that you're only needing a char. Reading a String and taking the first char from it didn't appear to me as the best solution.

Comment: My answer was based on the given question and example.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line:

```
        salir = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

after this line:

```
        System.out.print(" desea ingresar mas datos (Y/N)");
```